# Probability solution explanation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, proof-explanation

Question: Let $X=(Y, Z)$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and we assume that it has density given by

$$
f(y, z)= \begin{cases}c \sqrt{y^{2}+z^{2}} & y^{2}+z^{2} \leq 1 \\ 0 & \text { otherwise }\end{cases}
$$

for any $y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ and some unknown constant $c>0$. Let $(R, \Phi)$ be random variables with

$$
Y=R \cos (\Phi), \quad Z=R \sin (\Phi)
$$

where we assume that $Y>0$ and $\Phi$ is $[0,2 \pi)$-valued.

Find the absolute expectation of $X$ that is

$$
\mathrm{E}(|X|)
$$

where $|X|=\sqrt{Y^{2}+Z^{2}}$

---

---

---

Answer:

We have $|X|=R$ and the density of $R$ is given by

$$
f_{R}(r)=\int_{0}^{2 \pi} f_{R, \Phi}(r, \phi) d \phi= \begin{cases}3 r^{2} & r \in(0,1) and  0 & \text { otherwise. }\end{cases}
$$

consequently,

$$
\mathrm{E}(|X|)=\mathrm{E}(R)=\int_{0}^{1} r \cdot f_{R}(r) d r=\int_{0}^{1} 3 r^{3} d r=\frac{3}{4}
$$

---

---

---

My question is how, in the solution, did we get this part: $3 r^{2}$ when $r \in(0,1)$ and  0 otherwise. Where did the $3r^{2}$ come from?

This is not a homework problem so please feel free to be as elaborate as possible in your answer. I'm just trying to understand the material. Help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to compute the distribution of $R$ is to note that
$$
\mathbb E[f(R)] = \mathbb E[f(\sqrt{Y^2 + Z^2})] = c\int_{\Vert (y,z)\Vert_2^2\leq 1} f\left(\sqrt{y^2 + z^2}\right)\sqrt{y^2+z^2}d{y}d{z}.
$$
Then you can continue by using polar coordinates

> $$\mathbb E[f(R)] = c\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} f(r) r\cdot rd\phi dr = 2\pi c \int_0^1 f(r) r^2 dr.$$

In particular, the density of $r$ is of the form $C r^2$. To be a density, we need to choose $C$ such that
$$
1 = C\int_0^1 r^2 dr = C\cdot \dfrac{1}{3}
$$
i.e. $C = 3$.

Comment: How is C = 3? Don't worry, this is not a homework problem. I'm just trying to understand the material.

Comment: The density must integrate to 1. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I would also like to know how this: $c\int_{\Vert (y,z)\Vert_2^2\leq 1} f\left(\sqrt{y^2 + z^2}\right)\sqrt{y^2+z^2}d{y}d{z}$ became this:$c\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} f(r) r\cdot rd\phi dr$. Thanks.

Comment: This is obtained via the [substitution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables). You can also look up polar coordinates on Wikipedia to find the Jacobian. The only thing you use is that $\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$ is exactly the radius of the polar coordinates.